# how can i create a collection in a document which is in a collection in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I would like every time the user makes a purchase to be saved in a sub-collection in his corresponding document in the collection where his/her data are located, but I can't do it, could someone tell me how to write it in code form?

**the one highlighted in yellow is where I would like the user's purchases to be colored obviously for each document not in a single document in summary for each user who makes a purchase I would like a document to be created within the user's document in a subcollection**
[image]

Comment: to do that u need to DocId which is generated by Firebase(the middle Column of ur pic). then u can use collection.set() method to update

Comment: Could you give me a code example? thanks i have this code but it does not work  Future createCollectionInUserDocument() async {
    User? user = _auth.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      String uid = user.uid;
      DocumentReference userDocRef = _firestore.collection('ordini').doc(uid);
      CollectionReference userCollectionRef = userDocRef.collection('utenti');
    }
  }

Comment: let me give u a hint . Create a new collection name "orders", when a user orders something then do this _firestore.collection('orders').doc('...userId....').add({ purchased info in json format }).

Comment: I'll try but where will the json saves?

Comment: do that & check ur Firebase

Comment: doesnt  work this solution